# Simple Batch Script for File Consolidation - Beginner Problems

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-rename

I have identical files in four folders (named "1", "2", "3", "4") and would like to copy these files into a single folder, with the original folder name appended to the filename.

E.g. a file called "data.txt" in each folder should be copied to a new merged folder, with filenames such as "data 1.txt" "data 2.txt" etc.

Here is what I have so far, but I never formally learned batch scripting (and can't find any decent tutorials - recommendations please?) and can't seem to make it work. Hopefully this gives an idea of what I want to accomplish.

```dos
DIR="$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )" // I don't understand this but was told it's 
                                  // necessary to set the working directory as 
                                  // the current folder? Is that correct?
md "consolidated files"
for %%i in ("1","2","3","4") do
    copy *.txt '../consolidated files/"*"+%%i.txt'
```

Any tips for a beginner? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
PUSHD "U:\sourcedir"
MD "consolidated files" 2>nul
for %%i in ("1","2","3","4") DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%m IN ('dir /b /a-d ".\%%~i\*.txt"') DO (
  copy ".\%%~i\%%m" ".\consolidated files\%%~nm %%~i%%~xm"
 )
)
popd
GOTO :EOF
```

Your attempt to set `dir` appears to be a *bash* command - useful on *nix but no good on `CMD`.

Essentially, you can set the current directory using `cd`

```
cd "c:\your\desired directory"
```

Quirkishly, the quotes in that *particular* command are actually unnecessary (but do no harm, so I put them in.)

Another approach is

```
pushd "c:\your\desired directory"
rem commands following have current directory "c:\your\desired directory"
rem
popd
rem current directory reestored to value before the "pushd"
```

I've used the second approach in the above script to switch temporarily to my test directory `U:\sourcedir`

Note that `cmd` uses `\` as a directory-separator and `/` as a switch-indicator.

The `md` command is as you had it. The directory is created relative to the current directory unless the path is specified (eg `md "C:\somewhere new"). The`2>nul`suppresses the`directory already exists` message should the directory er, already exist.

in a `for...do` statement, either the target operation must be on the same line as the `do` or the `do` must be followed by <kbd>Space</kbd>( and then each statement until a matching `)` is executed as a compound statement.

The `for..%%i` statement assigns the values `"1"`..`"4"` (including the quotes) to `%%i` The quotes are actually not required in this case - they only **need** to be there if the required string includes a <kbd>Space</kbd> (or other separator.)

The next command is best understood from the middle. The `dir` command looks in ".\%%~i\" for files named `*.txt`. `~i` means "remove quotes from %%i". The `/b` switch shows just filenames - no size, date or header/footer. The `/a-d` switch says 'no directories'.

This `dir` command is within single-quotes. `FOR /f ...('single-quoted command')...` processes the result of the command as if it was a file, line-by-line. The `"delims="` suppresses the default tokenising of the strings found, so overall, the filenames found by the `dir` are assigned to `%%m` in their entirity.

The command then executed is the `copy`, copying from `".\%%~i\%%m"` (ie. the current directory++the subdirectory(-quotes)++filename; all quoted in case of spaces) to `".\consolidated files\%%~nm %%~i%%~xm"` (ie. the current directory+\consolidated files+the name part of the filename (%%~nm)+<kbd>Space</kbd>+the subdirectory(-quotes)+the extension part of the filename (%%~xm))

Note that `+` is a valid filename character (as is `'`) and that strings are built simply by being butted up one against the next.

Your original question stated that the source directoryname  should be appended after a space, hence I've included the space.

Note that `copy` will report `1 file(s) copied` after each copy. You can suppress this by adding `>nul` to the end of the `copy` statement.

For testing, I would change `copy` to `echo copy` which will show the command generated but not execute it. Unfortunately, if you have the `>nul` in place, the `echo` of the command will be suppressed...